# Persist derived objects using Mongo C# driver

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have the following class hierarchy

```
[BsonKnownTypes(typeof(MoveCommand))]
public abstract class Command : ICommand
{
    public abstract string Name
    {
        get;
    }

    public abstract ICommandResult Execute();
}
    public class MoveCommand : Command
{
    public MoveCommand()
    {
        this.Id = ObjectId.GenerateNewId().ToString();
    }

    [BsonId]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public override string Name
    {
        get { return "Move Command"; }
    }

    public override ICommandResult Execute()
    {
        return new CommandResult { Status = ExecutionStatus.InProgress };
    }
}
```

if I save the command like so:

```
 Command c = new MoveCommand();
MongoDataBaseInstance.GetCollection<Command>("Commands").Save(c);
```

and then query the DB, I don't see the derived properties persisted.

{ "_id" : "4df43312c4c2ac12a8f987e4", "_t" : "MoveCommand" }

I would expect a Name property as a key in the document.
What am I doing wrong?

Also, is there a way to avoid having a BsonKnowTypes attribute on the base class for persisting derived instances? I don't see the why a base class needs to know about derived classes. This is bad OO design and is being forced on my class hierarchy by the BSON library. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1.`Name` property was not saved into database because it haven't setter. Serializers not serialize properties that's haven't setters (because if serializer serialize such property  it will not able deserialize it back). So if you want serialize `Name` property then just add fake setter(into `ICommand` need to add it also):

```
  public override string Name
  {
    get { return "Move Command"; }
    set{}
  }
```

2.If you don't want use BsonKnownTypes attribute there is another way to notify serializer about know types it might encounter during deserialization. Just Register maps once, on app start event:

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<MoveCommand>();
//all other inherited from ICommand classes need register here also
```

So you should use or `KnownTypes` attribute or register `BsonClassMap` for each polymorphic class,  otherwise you will get 'unknown descriminator'  error during deserializtion:

```
  var commands = col.FindAllAs<ICommand>().ToList();
```

3 You said:

> This is bad OO design and is being
>   forced on my class hierarchy by the
>   BSON library.

In any way even without `KnownTypes` atribute your code using Bson lib through `BsonId` attribute.
If you want avoid it you can:

```
   BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<MoveCommand>(cm => {
        cm.AutoMap();
        cm.SetIdMember(cm.GetMemberMap(c => c.Id));
    });
```

So now you can remove reference to `Mongodb.Bson` lib from your domain code lib.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks a bunch. How can I register the ID generator instead of using this.id = ObjectId.GenerateNewId().ToString();
like I have in my ctor? Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I answered my own question:                                  cm.SetIdMember(cm.GetMemberMap(c => c.Id).SetIdGenerator            (new StringObjectIdGenerator()));

Comment: @Andrew Orsich: I'm unable to use the FindAllAs on an interface. I tried the FindAllAs as shows in your answer but I get the following error: "No serializer found for type ICommand", seems to work fine if I have a base class instead of an interface. Any thoughts?

Comment: @AbhijeetPatel: I guess you need remove old data from database and try again. In general i tried with base class but not with interface. So i will try findallas with interface later.

Comment: @Andrew: Yes, I removed all old data and tried, but it does not work with Interface, only with a base class. I'd be interested in knowing your findings.

Comment: Deserializing to an interface is not currently supported. I am working on adding support for that. The issue is that you cannot actually instantiate an instance of an interface, only classes can be instantiated. Currently the class to instantiate is determined by the class provided to the FindAllAs method. However, in principle if you provide an interface the actual class could be determined from the _t discriminator instead (if _t is present).

Comment: @Robert:Thanks for the clarification. Makes sense to be able to use _t  to infer the type, having the ability to use an interface would help by not burning the only base class available for inheritance.